# sql bulk update from associative array

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a table and use different update values based on different where values:

```
[
"2" => "7",
"5" => "23"
]
```

above data should cause all rows with columnA = 2 to update columnB = 7 and rows with columnA = 5 to columnB = 23.

Can I do this in one query or do I need to use individual update queries?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein mysql

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for your specific case is following (it is fast and readable):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
    columnB =
        CASE columnA 
            WHEN 2 THEN 7
            WHEN 5 THEN 23
        END
WHERE columnA IN (2, 5)
```

Also, you can operate without `WHERE`. But it could less effective for big tables since `columnB` would be reassigned in each row with its' current value everywhere where `columnA NOT IN (2, 5)`:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
    columnB =
        CASE columnA 
            WHEN 2 THEN 7
            WHEN 5 THEN 23
            ELSE columnB -- reassign the same value instead of using WHERE
        END
```

And if your conditions are not about one column equals to different values use complex `CASE` notation (conditions are located directly after `WHEN`):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
    ColumnB =
        CASE 
            WHEN columnA = 2 THEN 7
            WHEN columnA = 5 AND 1 = 1 THEN 23 -- FOR EXAMPLE
            ELSE ColumnB
        END
```

A little joke at the end.
Try a bit of math (2 => 7, 5 => 23):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET columnA = (11 * columnB * columnB + 83 * columnB) / 30
WHERE columnA IN (2, 5)
```